# CIDetector with AVCaptureOutput

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I am trying to detect smiles frame by frame from video input with AVFoundation and CIDetector. CIDetector is very inconsistent in terms of accuracy when used in captureOutput. The same facial expression can bounce from smiling to not smiling very fast depending on lighting, distance from camera, and other faces in the picture. Is there a way to make CIDetector less jittery without making it much slower?

```
@interface CameraViewController () {
    BOOL smiling;
}

...

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {

    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CFDictionaryRef attachments = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate);
    CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer options:(__bridge NSDictionary *)attachments];

    if (attachments)
        CFRelease(attachments);

    //CIImage translates all the pixels -90 deg; set orientation taking this into account

    NSNumber *orientation;
    switch ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation) {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            orientation = @6;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            orientation = @8;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            orientation = @3;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            orientation = @1;
            break;
        default:
            orientation = @6;
            break;
    }

    NSArray *faces = [[[SmileDetector sharedDetector] detector] featuresInImage:ciImage
                                                                        options:@{CIDetectorSmile: @(YES), CIDetectorImageOrientation:orientation}];
    smiling = NO;
    for (CIFaceFeature* face in faces)
        if (face.hasSmile) {
            smiling = YES;
            break;
        }
}
```

SmileDetector is a singleton for using the same instance of CIDetector in other ViewControllers. I set the detector accuracy to Low because High is too slow.

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                                      context:[CIContext contextWithOptions:nil]
                                      options:@{CIDetectorAccuracy:CIDetectorAccuracyLow}];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Maybe just change the accuracy? `@{CIDetectorAccuracy:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh}`

Comment: Tried, too slow: the frame updates before CIDetector has analyzed the last frame.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently dealing with the same issue and I have found that pre-processing the frames to stabilize contrast and brightness prior to CIDetector doing its work has worked quite well. My project is with still frames, I don't know how well that will work with video frames...

Comment: Nope, if you add the auto adjustment call (` let adjustments = sourceImg.autoAdjustmentFilters()`), it further delays the execution